# Amnah user extension in Yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2

I want to make a page to show information about the currently logged in user, but when i try to

```
echo Yii::$app->user->identity
```

it doesn't work because it can't convert the information to a string. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: you can't because `Yii::$app->user->identity` is an object of class User

Answer (score 0):

Actually solved it by using

```
Yii::$app->user->displayName
```